# How do i get row,column coordinates on selected String in excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

how to get row, column coordinate in an excel file?
I'm trying to confirm that user name is in the file. So i try to create a loop that read all the input in the excel file and find the same name as the user name and return the row and column. This is my code.

```
 private int ReadName(String Name){

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = librarianSheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING){
                String random = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
            }
            if(random == Name){

            }
        }
    }
    //return ;
}
```

But i seems to stuck there because i don't know what to do to get the desirable output. Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the desired name, return the cell.

```
private Cell readName(String name){
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = librarianSheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if(cell.getCellType() == CellType.STRING){
                String random = cell.getStringCellValue();
                if(random.equals(name)){
                    return cell;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
Cell cell = readName("Muhammad");
if(cell != null) {
    int column = cell.getColumnIndex();
    int row = cell.getRowIndex();
}
```